# REST endpoint name for "logging out" with a token

Tags: rest, api, jwt

I want to create an endpoint for "logging out". Logging out in my case is basically removing an access token from the database. Therefore DELETE verb makes sense here, something like this: DELETE URL/tokens. Now in terms of rest it makes sense to have URL/tokens/, however it is generally not acceptable to put an access token in the url and rather should be put in the header. Doing the latter, however, would leave the endpoint as URL/tokens only which could imply deleting all the tokens. What do you think?

Comment: Just do a POST to a Logout endpoint.  You don't need strict REST semantics here, as you're not dealing with an actual *resource.*

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. Something like `/users/{user_id}/logout` would suffice.

Comment: shouldn't you be passing the userId instead of actual token here

Comment: Well, he was asking for REST "abiding" and saying "don't use REST" is not an answer.

Comment: @Rob: It's a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge), and that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the *content* of the token doesn't need to be the only way of *identifying* that token. As a comparison, if you were designing an endpoint to delete an uploaded image from the server, you wouldn't expect the URL to contain the entire content of the image to be deleted. Instead, you'd identify the image by its name, or some arbitrary ID.

Similarly, you could have some sort of identifier for the token - probably a short string which is random but not secret, embedded as a claim inside the JWT. This might be useful for other purposes - correlating logs for the "session", for instance. Then the REST endpoint might be `DELETE /token/abc123` where `abc123` is not the token itself, but the ID inside it. The permission to delete that token would be granted by your normal authentication mechanism - the actual token in an HTTP header.

An advantage of this is that you can force a token to expire without having that token. For instance, some services can show users where they are currently logged in, and allow them to end specific sessions, e.g. if they accidentally left a session open on a shared computer.

Secondly, a URL's meaning can *vary based on who is authenticated*. An obvious example is that you might have access to only some fields of a resource, so the representation returned would depend what authentication token you presented. Taken further, that means you can have URLs which explicitly refer to the current user - a URL like `/users/me` can return whichever user authenticates to it.

Using a similar self-referencing URL, you could have an end-point that deleted the *current* token, e.g. `DELETE /token/current`. This could sit alongside the above ID-based mechanism.

---

A quick side-note about REST: some advocates of REST as originally envisioned will point out that URLs should not be hand-crafted at all, everything should be managed with "hypermedia". That is, to log out, you would need to first GET a resource that let you "discover" the token's management URL, and then send a DELETE to that URL. The actual URL might be `/af4de9a3-d055-4808-932b-9c580e082232` with no way to guess it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that [passing sensitive information](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#sensitive-information-in-http-requests) in URIs is a bad practice from a security perspective.  The upshot is that doing so makes it more likely that the information will be exposed e.g. in web logs.

> Doing the latter, however, would leave the endpoint as URL/tokens only which could imply deleting all the tokens.

There's some merit to this but I think you are overthinking things a bit.  You could change the resource to URL/token (singular) which will make it pretty clear that the specific resource needs to be identified.